# Merging records based on consecutive dates in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge records of my dataframe if dates are same.Here in the below example I want to merge date (13,14,15), (25,26), (30,31) together as there are continuous dates. I want to break the merging of record if there is any single day break.

```
      cust               date         description
   CUST123              2020-06-13   observed increased loss rate
   CUST123              2020-06-13   cut performed job
   CUST123              2020-06-14   working tight area
   CUST123              2020-06-15   production shut neighbouring app
   CUST123              2020-07-17   loss pressure slow gain trip
   CUST123              2020-08-25   established circulation load
   CUST123              2020-08-26   performed sticky test
   CUST123              2020-08-28   job meeting prior low energy
   CUST123              2020-08-30   performed maintenance service
   CUST123              2020-08-31   reconnected control line
```

expected output

```
      cust               date         description
   CUST123              2020-06-13   observed increased loss rate cut performed job 
                                      working tight area production shut neighbouring app
   CUST123              2020-07-17   loss pressure slow gain trip
   CUST123              2020-08-25   established circulation load performed sticky test
   CUST123              2020-08-28   job meeting prior low energy
   CUST123              2020-08-30   performed maintenance service reconnected control line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to merge records of a dataframe if dates are same, you could do:

```
merged_df = df.groupby(['cust', 'date'])['description'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

which outputs:

```
cust       date                                     description
0  CUST123 2020-06-13  observed increased loss rate cut performed job
1  CUST123 2020-06-14                              working tight area
2  CUST123 2020-06-15                production shut neighbouring app
3  CUST123 2020-07-17                    loss pressure slow gain trip
4  CUST123 2020-08-25                    established circulation load
5  CUST123 2020-08-26                           performed sticky test
6  CUST123 2020-08-28                    job meeting prior low energy
7  CUST123 2020-08-30                   performed maintenance service
8  CUST123 2020-08-31                        reconnected control line
```

---

EDIT: If you want to merge the consecutive dates, keeping the first date of the consecutive range, you could it like this:

```
# Sort DataFrame by 'date' (in case 'df' is not already sorted)
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)

# Initialize variables
merged_data = []
prev_row = None

# Loop through the rows
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if prev_row is None or row['cust'] != prev_row['cust'] or (row['date'] - prev_row['date']).days > 1:
        merged_data.append({'cust': row['cust'], 'date': row['date'], 'description': row['description']})
    else:
        merged_data[-1]['description'] += ' ' + row['description']
    prev_row = row

# Create merged DataFrame
merged_df = pd.DataFrame(merged_data)

print(merged_df)
```

Output:

```
0  CUST123 2020-06-13  observed increased loss rate cut performed job...
1  CUST123 2020-07-17                       loss pressure slow gain trip
2  CUST123 2020-08-25  established circulation load performed sticky ...
3  CUST123 2020-08-28                       job meeting prior low energy
4  CUST123 2020-08-30  performed maintenance service reconnected cont...
```

Comment: I have updated my question to get more clarification. I need to merge all those dates records which are consecutive.

Comment: @Adityasharma I updated my post to exactly answer your question.

Comment: this `row['cust'] != prev_row['cust']` line is giving error as `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`. As prev_row is None.

Comment: X_new_transformed = pipe.named_steps['tfidf'].transform(X_new)
pipe.named_steps['xgboost training'].fit(X_new_transformed, y_new)

Comment: def find_labels(description):
    labels = []
    for keyword, label in dictionary.items():
        if keyword in description:
            labels.append(label)
    return "/".join(labels) if labels else None

# Apply the function to create the 'label' column
df['label'] = df['description'].apply(find_labels)